# Initialization and management of a shared_ptr to base interface

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, raii, ownership-semantics

I have some questions related to the use of a shared_ptr pointing to a base class. Their answers influence each other, and for all three I need the same code snippet to set the context in as minimal a way as possible, like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/514a1d81972eb971) (all the questions relate to `Foo` and its `held_object_`):

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class Bar  // interface for Scene (see linked question)
{
public:
  virtual ~Bar() = 0;
  // more virtual methods to work with Scene
};

Bar::~Bar() = default;

class Baz : public Bar // interface for Foo
{
public:
  virtual ~Baz() = 0;
  // more virtual methods to work with Foo
};

Baz::~Baz() = default;

class ConcreteBaz : public Baz // actual thing I'm acquiring and releasing
{
// overrides and whatnot
};

class Foo
{
public:
  void acquire(const std::shared_ptr<Baz>& object) {};
  void release(/* actually takes a place to release into */) {};

private:
  std::shared_ptr<Baz> held_object_;
};

int main()
{  
  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  auto p_foo = foo.get();

  while (/* condition */)
  {
    auto cbaz = std::make_shared<ConcreteBaz>();
    // Scene gets a copy here

    p_foo->acquire(cbaz);
    // do physical things to cbaz
    p_foo->release(/* actually takes a place to release into */);

    // do other physical things, then acquire cbaz again

    p_foo->acquire(cbaz);
    // do physical things to cbaz
    p_foo->release(/* actually takes a place to release into */);
  }
}
```

As you can see `cbaz` is a pointer to a polymorphic hierarchy that can work with both `Scene` and `Foo`. `ConcreteBaz` actually represents a **physical entity** which a `Foo` can, as stated in the code, take ownership of (it's a `shared_ptr` because both `Scene` and `Foo` own it, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444116/ownership-with-a-physical-representation). I removed details of `Scene` here because it's OT).

### Questions

**1) How do I initialize `held_object_`? Can I do it with a single allocation?**

In reality, `foo` doesn't own `cbaz` until it (physically) gets it, therefore the constructor should initialize the pointer to nullptr. Initially I wanted to use `make_shared` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289919/9926122) but I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45366469/9926122) that it value-initializes, meaning if I were to do

```
Foo::Foo()
    : held_object_ {std::make_shared<Baz>()} // equivalent to std::make_shared<Baz>(nullptr)
{
}
```

the compiler would complain with `error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type`. This *would* thus become a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13311755/9926122) question but the accepted answer either leaves the `shared_ptr` uninitialized or creates a further `unique_ptr` to... basically it's unclear how I would apply it here, and I don't think I can call `reset` in the constructor (?).

Should I instead be explicit and say

```
Foo::Foo()
    : held_object_ {std::shared_ptr<Baz> {nullptr}}
{
}
```

without caring for the double allocation which `make_shared` avoids? At this point wouldn't it be almost exactly identical to just `: held_object_ {}` (move ctor vs. default ctor aside)?
EDIT: Can I do it with a single allocation as well, like `make_shared` [does](https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/29/gotw-89-solution-smart-pointers/)?

**2) How do I manage `held_object_`?**

Right now to get ownership of `cbaz` after calling `acquire` I eventually get into a call for method

```
void Foo::setHeldObject_(std::shared_ptr<Baz> object)
{
  this->held_object_ = std::move(object);
}
```

however in `release` I will have to destroy the owning `shared_ptr` (to then set it again come next loop) and make the state of my `Foo` instance coherent with its physical state IRL. This had me thinking of using [std::shared_ptr::reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) (before even reading the previous related answer) because I would replace the pointee with nullptr if I called `setHeldObject()` and set `cbaz` otherwise. However I can't figure the correct syntax to the method's body as:

- `this->held_object_.reset(object);` is obviously wrong, as I want to manage the pointee, not the pointer (and doesn't therefore compile);
- `this->held_object_.reset(&object);` looks wrong, and yields `error: cannot convert ‘std::shared_ptr<Baz>*’ to ‘Baz*’ in initialization`
- `this->held_object_.reset(object.get());` also seems wrong because I don't think I'm upping the `user_count` this way (it does compile though).

EDIT: I believe it should be possible to do it with the same method call, giving or not giving the argument. Would that be possible with `reset`?

**3) There are really only two owners**

The `main` function I wrote here is actually a `Process` class' `run` method, but having it defined like this makes it so the use_count bumps to 3 by the time `Scene` and `Foo` have their own `shared_ptr`. From when I `make_shared` onwards, I'm inside a loop, moreover the logic says there should be only two owners. Is this a use case for `weak_ptr` where it could make sense to do something like:

```
int main()
{  
  auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
  auto p_foo = foo.get();

  while (/* condition */)
  {
    auto cbaz = std::make_shared<ConcreteBaz>();
    auto p_cbaz = std::weak_ptr<ConcreteBaz> {cbaz};
    // Scene gets a && via std::move here

    p_foo->acquire(p_cbaz.lock()); // this instantly gets converted to a shared_ptr EDIT: BUT IT DOESN'T INCREASE THE USE COUNT
    // do physical things to cbaz
    p_foo->release(/* actually takes a place to release into */);

    // do other physical things, then acquire cbaz again

    p_foo->acquire(p_cbaz.lock()); // this instantly gets converted to a shared_ptr and would be nullptr had I moved in the first acquire call EDIT: BUT IT DOESN'T INCREASE THE USE COUNT
    // do physical things to cbaz
    p_foo->release(/* actually takes a place to release into */);
  }
}
```

or is there a better way?

Comment: `held_object_ ` will be initialized properly, don't sweat this, default initialize it. Use std::move, yes. That's the proper way of getting the counter. and `reset(nullptr)` to release it. Third question, that's opinion based and depending on the rest of the design. May not really matter.

Comment: `held_object_ {std::shared_ptr<Baz> {nullptr}}` does no allocation at all, and is equivalent to default-initialization.

Comment: @Quentin did I misunderstand the purpose of `make_shared` from the linked article?

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica No, you are just overestimating the gains it brings.

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica the lesser equivalent of `std::make_shared` would be `std::shared_ptr<Baz>{new Baz}`, but here you're initializing with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I initialize `held_object_`

If you want `held_object_` to be `nullptr` then you don't have to do anything.  The compiler generated default constructor of `Foo` will call `held_object_`s default constructor leaving it as a null pointer.

> How do I manage `held_object_`

When you need to release the ownership of the pointer you just call `reset` without any parameters.  That effectively does `shared_ptr().swap(*this);` which leaves you with a null pointer.

Comment: I really don't have an answer for 3.  I'm not sure why you need `use_count` to only be 2.  It's okay if the creator of the pointer shares the ownership until it returns and that local copy is destroyed.

Comment: Because semantically there should only be only two owners, `Foo` and `Scene`. Besides, I read everywhere that "`shared_ptr` is incremented atomically and that's expensive", and since I'm creating said pointer inside a loop I want to do it the right amount of times.

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica If you really only want 2 owners max then one of the objects you give the pointer to you should use `std::move(cbaz)` so it move it from the calling function into the owning object.  Then your left with a null pointer and `use_count` will only be 2.

Comment: I can't do that: were I to `move` into `scene` I would lose a way to give ownership to `foo`, and conversely I actually have two calls to `acquire` within the loop (same physical object, I have to do stuff to it in a place and than other things in another), so I need the logic to be there, that's why I was thinking of `weak_ptr`

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica The weak pointer gains you nothing.  Either copy into `scene` and move into `foo` or have a shared pointer in `run`. If you could  call acquire multiple times then you probably need the latter.  A single extra atomic increment/decrement isn't going to do much.

Comment: I added the looping logic which was previously missing, this should make it more clear

Comment: @LaboratorioCobotica With the way you loop looks and what you want to do I can't see how you could have less than 3 owners.  `run`, scene` and `foo` are all using the pointer at the same time. I guess you could give `scene` the pointer, get a reference back to it from `scene`, copy that into `foo` so now `scene` and `foo` own the pointer and `run` has a reference to it.  It'd be silly to do but it gets the use count down.  I wouldn't really worry about it though.  More than likely that extra atomic operation is going to get lost in the noise of the loop.

Comment: I just saw weak_ptr doesn't work like I thought in my example (it doesn't increment the use_count, mainly), so I'll follow your advice and worry about it in an optimization phase, even though the design isn't quite perfect. I'll just edit the example to make it compile in case someone wants to try it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How do I initialize held_object_?

You can just do this:

```
Foo::Foo()
    : held_object_ {nullptr}
{
}
```

But that's of course equivalent to `: held_object_ {}`, albeit slightly more explicit in your intent. Another alternative would be to have

```
class Foo
{
  // ...
private:
  std::shared_ptr<Baz> held_object_ = nullptr;
};
```

> 2) How do I manage held_object_?

Your first version with the `std::move` is just fine. Do note that you only partake in ownership this way, you don't get exclusive ownership (which is why I would not name the method `acquire`).

> 3) There are really only two owners

I don't think you can get a real answer to this one, as it's both dependent on your exact situation and (even given that) somewhat opinion-based. Also, don't sweat the use count unless you're actually in it for performance. Writing different code because you are worried about some minute performance detail (cost of reference count in `shared_ptr`) is premature optimization unless you have very good reasons to believe (or proof) that it will be a problem. Do you do this in an inner loop? If not, a spurious refcount up/down won't be felt.

Comment: Why even declaring it? Just remove the clutter.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Because e.g. Lint will yell at you for not initializing your members. By explicitly initializing like shown, there is no doubt that what happens is intended. Of course, you could just default-initialize with `= nullptr` at the declaration instead.

Comment: Lint may tell you this, and clang-tidy says exactly the opposite. I'm for readability, not clutter.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher That was copied from the OP. Re Lint: That's your opinion, which is fine but not absolute.

Comment: I am doing it in a loop, actually, as per `The part with acquire and release is actually in a loop` somewhere up top. Should have made it more evident